# how can send custom type array of objects from node.js to postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, object

I have angular and node.js app, and i try to insert into postgres db custom type, which looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE t_speed AS ( time Date, speed integer );
```

this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
  id_sportman integer, 
  start_date timestamp, 
  id_type_activity integer, 
  distance numeric, 
  id_district integer, 
  name varchar(255), 
  gpx_file_name varchar(255), 
  gpx_file text, 
  time_in_seconds integer, 
  speeds t_speed[]
);
```

i am able to insert new object type from node.js:

```
const postActivity = async (pool: any, req: any) => { let activity = req.body; let file = req.file;

const tcxDestination = "path";

const newFilePath = tcxDestination + "/" + file.filename;

const tcxContent = await fs.readFile(newFilePath, "utf-8"); const { startTime, timeInSeconds, distanceInKm} = await extractDataFromGpx(tcxContent);

const data = { time: new Date(), speed: 120 };

await pool.query(`INSERT INTO activities(
  id_sportman, 
  start_date, 
  id_type_activity, 
  distance, 
  id_district, 
  name, 
  gpx_file_name, 
  gpx_file, 
  time_in_seconds, speeds
) 
VALUES 
  (
    $1, 
    $2, 
    $3, 
    $4, 
    1, 
    $5, 
    $6, 
    $7, 
    $8, 
    ($9, $10)
`), [ activity.idSportman, startTime, activity.idTypeActivity, distanceInKm, activity.name, newFilePath, tcxContent, timeInSeconds, data.date, data.speed ] ); };
```

but i am unable to found out how array of objects, can you help me please?

i try this:

```
const postActivity = async (pool: any, req: any) => {
  let activity = req.body;
  let file = req.file;

  const tcxDestination =
    "C:/Users/frede/Desktop/DIPLOMKA/diplomka-app/Diplomka/BE/src";

  const newFilePath = tcxDestination + "/" + file.filename;

  const tcxContent = await fs.readFile(newFilePath, "utf-8");
  const { startTime, timeInSeconds, distanceInKm, heartRatesData, timestamps } =
    await extractDataFromGpx(tcxContent);

  
  const heartRatesArray = timestamps.map((timestamp, index) => `('${timestamp}', ${heartRatesData[index]})`);
  console.log(heartRatesArray)
  await pool.query(
    `INSERT INTO activities(id_sportman, start_date, id_type_activity, distance, id_district, name, gpx_file_name, gpx_file, time_in_seconds, heart_rates)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, 1, $5, $6, $7, $8, ARRAY[$9]::t_heart_rate[]`,
    [
      activity.idSportman,
      startTime,
      activity.idTypeActivity,
      distanceInKm,
      activity.name,
      newFilePath,
      tcxContent,
      timeInSeconds,
      heartRatesData.map((item) => [item.timestamp, item.heartRate])
    ]
  );
};
```

but it is not working